# DRF POST Image and Text at the same time

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is what my model looks like:

```py
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Thats all set. Dont worry about it.')
```

I have a standard serializer:

```py
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = "__all__"
```

And then there's my view:

```py
class ExampleView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ExampleModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file_serializer = ExampleSerializer(data=request.data)
        if file_serializer.is_valid():
            file_serializer.save()
            return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

What I want to know is 
 a) I'm trying to populate the text and model fields using Python requests. 
 `requests.post(url, headers="The tokens(Already taken care of)", "How to put in the body? Where and how do I add the image and text?"` 
 b) Is there something I need to change or add in either my serializer, view or something else to meet my requirement?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time reading this :)

EDIT: Also, how do I update an object that is already there? All I can find for this is in older Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) you can post text and image like this :

```
image_file = {'image': open('test.jpg', 'rb')}
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
} 
jsondata = {'text': 'hello_world'}
requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=jsondata, files=image_file)
```

b) there is no need to update the serializer

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this doesn't send the `data`, only the image.

Comment: Ok, removing the `"Content-Type"` from the headers worked.